# How to modify the order of symbols to make the result look more well and use some fixed expression 1-q, 1-c-q and so on?

Tags: expression-construction

[image]

In most cases, my expressions are quite complex, like the following expr and expr2. How can I make them look better, for instance, I want to use expressions like 1-q or 1-c-q and so on.

[image]

Comment: Please include Mathematica code in addition to the images. Thanks.

Comment: `TraditionalForm` moves variables first and constants last, which is the traditional way math people write expressions. You don't want it to do that. So do not use `TraditionalForm` and without that you seem to get some or maybe most of what you want. But I think you will not like that result either. Maybe find different math software that does EXACTLY and ONLY what you want and you may be much happier and much more productive.

Comment: You can change how an expression is presented by using the ComplexityFunction and Simplify.  However, for the ordering of symbols, I don’t believe that you can change that.  If I need the equation elsewhere, sometimes I’ll use the TeXForm and make my own adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
expr = (-2 q + (-1 + c + q) a)^2/(9 q a);
expr2 = 1/36 (-(a (5 q + 4) (c + q - 1)^2)/(((q - 1) q)) + 4 q/a);
```

You may first try pattern matching and StandardForm:

```
expr /. {x : (-1 + __) -> -x}
```

[image]

```
expr2 /.  {x : (-1 + __) :> -x}
```

[image]

This also works with TraditionalForm, but TraditionalForm puts the "1" at the end like:

```
expr /. {x : (-1 + __) -> -x} // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
expr2 /.  {x : (-1 + __) :> -x} // TraditionalForm
```

[image]